# How to upload date with bulkloader?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I have the following code in **bulkloader.yaml**:

```
  - property: dismissal_date
    external_name: dismissal_date
    import_transform: "lambda x: None if x is None or x=='' else datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y').date()"
```

**models.py**:

```
class Employee(ndb.Model):
    dismissal_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

and **upload file (csv)**:

```
last_name,first_name,middle_name,region,dismissal_date
Last name,First name,Middle name,22,13.01.2009
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
BadValueError: Unsupported type for property dismissal_date: <type 'datetime.date'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following actually works (which is strange since [the doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) says that I should use `.date()`):

```
import_transform: "lambda x: None if x is None or x=='' else datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y')"
```

[Source of transform.py](http://code.google.com/r/pklemenkov-document-editor/source/browse/thirdparty/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py) helped to identify that.

I've change property type to `DateProperty()`, but still date saved with time component (`00:00:00`).